# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10

Tags: bash, jq, parse-error

I have this script    and this startup error ( parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10 ) , what should I do? P.S. The file is written in bash.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATA=$(curl -s 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/' | jq -r '.data ."1" .quotes .USD .price')
echo $DATA
#printf "%0.0f\n" $DATA
```

Comment: That error is coming from `jq`, not `bash`.

Comment: If the shebang says `#!/bin/sh` this is not a Bash script. See [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: That API is no longer operating. It returns a page that displays an error message, not the JSON you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

With a valid API KEY, the following curl invocation:

```
curl -H "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY:$KEY" -H "Accept: application/json" \
-d "start=1&limit=5000&convert=USD" \
-G https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest
```

yields valid JSON, for which the jq query:

```
 jq '.data[0].quote.USD.price'
```

yields

```
32884.18011827609
```

Notes:

- arrays are indexed by integers, not strings;
- jq's "index origin" for arrays is 0;
- there is no need for the -r option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above in comments:

You should check what cURL is returning because the data you're trying to parse with `jq` isn't JSON. It's more likely an HTML error message that `jq` doesn't know how to parse.